# Number of times a record shows up : SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with just one field, say `Numbers`.
And it looks like this:

```
Numbers
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

What I want is an output of the number of times each number shows up.
For example, **1** has a count of **15**, **2** has a count of **33** and so on.

What is the query I would run to identify the number of occurrences?

Comment: Hi Ray, if you liked RedFilter's answer, you can mark accept it as correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select Numbers, count(*) as Count
from MyTable
group by Numbers
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Numbers, Count(Numbers)
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY Numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT Numbers, COUNT(1) FROM Table GROUP BY Numbers`